# Why (or when) can you just simplify $e^{-i\phi}$ to $|e^{-i\phi}|=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can transcribe this in LaTeX if it'd be preferable. I start with this to show that this is literally what's written in the PDF:

> [image]

Why (or when) can you just simplify $e^{-i\phi}$ to $|e^{-i\phi}|=1$?

I assume under the same conditions one could also simplify $e^{i\phi}$ to $|e^{i\phi}|=1$.

Comment: This is always true.

Comment: You need to provide more context. The 2nd equality $\,\sin a \sin \theta (\cos \Phi - i \sin \Phi) = \sin a \sin \theta\,$ is certainly not true in general.

Comment: One does not "simplify" an expression to an equation. One simplifies an expression to another expression, or an equation to another equation. Do you mean "for what $\phi$ is it true that $|e^{i\phi}|=1$?" If so, the answer is "when $\phi$ is real."

Comment: @elemelons - I just meant the equal signs there as "a.k.a."

Comment: To repeat @dxiv's point more forcefully, the PDF is wrong. It might be a nice exercise to understand why it is wrong, but if your main purpose was to learn some particular fact from the PDF, you might be better off looking for a better source.

Comment: @dxiv \@ChrisCulter - Ah, I see, thank you. I'm looking at a solutions manual for a book on quantum mechanics. I think like \@elemelons said there must some context that isn't explicit like some value being real (not sure how $\phi$ would _not_ be real in this case).

Comment: Hmm, if it's an official solutions manual by the publisher, it might have a list of errata online. If not, well... such things have to be treated with a certain amount of suspicion.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Just "*some value being real*" is not enough to make the equality in my 1st comment true.  Even if *all* of them are real, the equality can only hold true if $a = k \pi$ or $\theta = k \pi$ or $\Phi = 2 k \pi$. That's assuming, of course, that $\,\sin, \,\cos, \,'='\,$ are used with the standard meanings in *that* context.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{\pm i\phi}=\cos\phi\pm i\sin\phi$$

we have

$$e^{\pm i\phi}=1\Longleftrightarrow \cos\phi=1\cap\sin\phi=0\Longleftrightarrow \phi=2k\pi,~k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Therefore,

$e^{\pm i\phi}=1$ if and only if $\phi=2k\pi,~k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

Looking *solely* at the statement that $|e^{\pm i \phi}| = 1$, assuming that $\phi$ is a real number, we can use Euler's formula $e^{i \phi} = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi$ and the fact that for any complex number $z = x + iy$, $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Then

$\begin{eqnarray} \left|e^{\pm i \phi}\right| & = & \left|\cos (\pm \phi) + i \sin (\pm \phi)\right| \\
& = & \left| \cos \phi + i (\pm \sin \phi)\right| \\
& = & \sqrt{(\cos \phi)^2 + (\pm \sin \phi)^2} \\
& = & \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi} \\
& = & \sqrt{1} = 1
\end{eqnarray}$

I make no comments about the accuracy of the rest of the equality, which other people have already addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a theorem of Euler that $e^{i\phi}=cos\phi+isin\phi$; this is true *always*, for any $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$. (In fact, it is true for any $\phi\in\mathbb{C}$ as well if we extend the definitions of $cos$ and $sin$ to accept complex number inputs. Your pdf is likely focused on real inputs, so we'll digress from this point.) Since $cos(-\phi)=cos\phi$ and $sin(-\phi)=-sin\phi$, as they are even and odd functions respectively, we can combine these facts to get that $e^{-i\phi}=e^{i(-\phi)}=cos\phi-isin\phi$ *always* (for any $\phi\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{C}$) as well. Letting $z=x+iy$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, the fact that $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ lets us conclude that $|e^{i\phi}|=\sqrt{cos^2\phi+sin^2\phi}=\sqrt(1)=1$ and that $|e^{-i\phi}|=\sqrt{cos^2\phi+(-sin\phi)^2}=\sqrt{cos^2\phi+sin^2\phi}=\sqrt{1}=1$ -- again, *always* ($\phi\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{C}$).

The fact that $|e^{-i\phi}|=|cos\phi-isin\phi|=1$, however, does not allow you to conclude that $sin\alpha sin\theta(cos\phi-isin\phi)=sin\alpha sin\theta$. This equality holds if and only if $cos\phi-isin\phi=1$ (just divide by $sin\alpha sin\theta$ on both sides). A counterexample is that $i=e^{-i\frac{-\pi}{2}}=cos\frac{-\pi}{2}-isin\frac{-\pi}{2}$. In this case $sin\alpha sin\theta(cos\frac{-\pi}{2}-isin\frac{-\pi}{2})=isin\alpha sin\theta$.

Comment: You can use \sin and \cos in MathJax to avoid each letter being treated as a separate variable.